# mTLS/Client Certificate via HTTP Header

Tags: http-headers, client-certificates, azure-application-gateway

**Issue Description**

I have a use case in which I need to access an application protected by a gateway, which expects a client certificate. The application from which I am sending the request can do only HTTP, and doesn't allow any form/option for custom-code or extensions. I am wondering if I can pass the client certificate via the HTTP-Header. I am using Postman (https://www.postman.com/) for testing.

**What did I try so far?**

I have both the certificate file (*.cer) and the key file (*.key).

1. I have combined both the *.cer and *.key files in a single file, and converted this in base64. I have then passed it to the request header using the key `X-Client-Certificate`
2. I have used “openssl” to combine both *.cer and *.key file into a *.pfx file

```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes \
    -out mycert.pfx \
    -inkey mycert.key \
    -in mycert.cer \
    -passout pass:
```

and then converted this into base64. The base64 encoded certificate has been passed to the HTTP header `X-Client-Certificate`.

I have also tried different configurations with other kind of HTTP Headers such as `X-ARR-ClientCert`.

None of these combinations have worked. However, passing the certificate as described in the related Postman documentation (https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/) works as expected.

Can I expect this to work (using HTTP headers)? I yes, am I doing something wrong? Can you help?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I tried connecting API that uses Mutual TLS (mTLS) and added a client certificate to Postman like below:

[image]

Added client certificate like below:

[image]

***Note*** that: When you make an HTTPS request to a configured domain, Postman automatically sends the client certificate with the request. Postman doesn't send the certificate in Http request [refer](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/#using-a-certificate).

To send the request via HTTP, you can create rewrite rule to send client certificate to the backend as an HTTP header and you can verify the status of the client certificate in Online certificate status protocol the certificate presented by the client will be looked up via the defined OCSP responder defined in its Authority Information Access (AIA) extension.

[image]

To know more in detail, check the below references:

[Exploring mTLS setup to send a client certificate to the backend and OCSP validation | Azure Blog | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/exploring-mtls-setup-to-send-a-client-certificate-to-the-backend-and-ocsp-validation/) by rajesh-nautiyal

[Overview of mutual authentication on Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/mutual-authentication-overview?tabs=powershell)